# Netbeans OutOfMemoryError when running j2me apps

Tags: java-me, netbeans6.5

I always get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error when I try to run  any J2ME program in Netbeans (with the big green play icon). How can it be fixed? (I can run J2ME programs after I build them in netbeans and double-click on the generated JAD file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increaing the allowed heap space

Check [Tuning JVM switches for performance](http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/index.html)

There is a good thread for tuning eclipse: [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse 3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349)

Some of that may be useful to you